# Geometric meaning of the $L^p$-norm of $|A|$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let be $M$ an oriented smooth surface on $\mathbb{R}^3$, $|A|$ the norm of the second fundamental form of $M$ and $dV$ the element of area. I would like to know if there is a geometric meaning for the quantity $|| \ |A| \ ||_p^p = \int_M |A|^p dV$? I saw this appears in "A compactness theorem for surfaces with $Lp$-bounded second fundamental form" by Joel Langer and this seems an important quantity since the integrand $|A| = \sqrt{4H^2 - 2K}$ and the quantities $H$ and $K$ are invariant under change of the basis. I looked for an explanations about the $L^p$-norm of $|A|$ in Riemannian Geometry's textbooks and in Differential Geometry's textbooks, but I couldn't find nothing.

More generally, if $M$ is an oriented smooth $n$-manifold immersed on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $|A|$ the norm of the second fundamental form of $M$ and $dV$ the element of volume, then there is an geometric meaning for the quantity $|| \ |A| \ ||_p^p = \int_M |A|^p dV$? Again, it seems that there is an intepretation since $|A|^2 - \frac{H^2}{n} = \sum_{i < j} (\lambda_i - \lambda_j)^2$, where $\lambda_i$ are the principal curvatures of $M$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think for hypersurface in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $|A|^n=-R+n^2H^2$ where $R$ is scalar curvature. Not sure what $|A|^p$ represents.